# Loading navbar using Jquery doesnt work with electron

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, electron

I have used this piece of code on my website for quickly adding the navbar to all of my pages.

```
<!-- navbar-->
<div id="nav-placeholder">
</div>
<script>
$(function(){
$("#nav-placeholder").load("/templates/nav.html");
});
</script>
<!--end of Navigation bar-->
```

This works like a charm while using live server, however I now try to migrate my code to an electron application and now this doesn't work. I get no errors but i don't see any navbar. Does anyone know what I need to add to get this working?

I have added this line to my renderer.js

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

And imported renderer.js at the top of my html body using

```
<script src="./renderer.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is most likely not an issue with Electron. Have you verified that the `"/templates/nav.html"` path is correct? You can try `fetch`ing it from the renderer.

Comment: You are correct the problem was that you needed to change the path to "./templates/nav.html"